# Order By not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using this stored procedure for custom paging in a gridview, and I am getting an error when I use `ORDER BY`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetAllTender]
      @pageIndex int = 0
    , @pageSize int = 0
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   /* Set Starting Row Index and Ending Row Index */
   -------------------------------------------------  
   DECLARE @startRowIndex int = 0
   SET @startRowIndex = (@pageIndex * @pageSize) + 1

   DECLARE @endRowIndex int = 0
   SET @endRowIndex = (@startRowIndex + @pageSize - 1)

   /* recordCount required for paging in front end */
   DECLARE @recordCount int = 0
   SET @recordCount = 0

   -------------------------------------------------  
   SELECT
       @recordCount = COUNT(*)
   FROM [vwTenderDetail] A WITH (NOLOCK)

   SELECT
       TenderID,
       TenderRefNumber,
       TenderTitle,
       subProductCatName,
       CreatedDate,
       UserName,
       ModifiedDate,
       ModifiedUserName,
       tRecordCount
   FROM 
       (SELECT
           TD.TenderID,
           TD.TenderRefNumber,
           TD.TenderTitle,
           TD.SubProductCatName,
           TD.CreatedDate,
           TD.UserName,
           TD.ModifiedDate,
           TD.ModifiedUserName,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TD.TenderID) AS RowNum,
           @recordCount AS tRecordCount,
           TD.Enabled,
           COUNT(TC.TenderID) AS NoOFCorrigendum
        FROM 
           [vwTenderDetail] TD (NOLOCK)
        LEFT JOIN 
           TenderCorrigendum TC (NOLOCK) ON TD.TenderID = TC.TenderID
        WHERE 
           TD.Enabled = 1      
        GROUP BY 
           TD.TenderID, TD.TenderRefNumber, TD.TenderTitle, TD.SubProductCatName,
           TD.CreatedDate, TD.UserName, TD.ModifiedDate, TD.ModifiedUserName, TD.Enabled
        ORDER BY 
           TenderID DESC) AS TEMP
WHERE 
    RowNum BETWEEN @startRowIndex AND @endRowIndex
END
```

I am getting this error:

> Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spGetAllTender, Line 64
>   The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables,
>   subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is
>   also specified.

and when I am using `order by` after where it does `select top 10(PageSize)` rows and then order those 10 rows according to tenderid

Comment: Why do you need the `ORDER BY TenderID DESC` anyway if you're just doing a count? Actually the error message is self-explanatory. `ORDER BY clause is invalid in (...) subqueries `

Comment: The error clearly states that you cannot use `Order by` inside a `subquery`. It should be used in the outermost query

Comment: The error is fairly explicit in what is wrong - where is the issue?

Comment: Looks like you are intended to do PAGING, If so you can simplify your paging logic just by using OFFSET FETCH. Check out(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx). This works only on SQL 2012.

Comment: I need result order by TenderID that's why i am using  ORDER BY TenderID DESC

Comment: Please format the query for better understanding.

Comment: INNER query shouldn't contain `ORDER BY`. That's the problem in your case.

Comment: @kartik then how to get rows in a order

Comment: a simple way around is to add a `SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT`

Comment: and when i am using order by after where it select top 10(PageSize)
rows and then order those 10 rows according to tenderid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetAllTender]  
  @pageIndex int= 0  
, @pageSize int= 0  
AS  
BEGIN  
  SET NOCOUNT ON;  
  /* Set Starting Row Index and Ending Row Index */  
  DECLARE @startRowIndex int= 0  
  SET @startRowIndex =(@pageIndex * @pageSize)+ 1  
  DECLARE @endRowIndex int= 0  
  SET @endRowIndex =(@startRowIndex + @pageSize - 1)  
  /* recordCount required for paging in front end */  
  DECLARE @recordCount int= 0  
  SET @recordCount = 0  

  SELECT  
   @recordCount =COUNT(*)  
   FROM [vwTenderDetail] A WITH (NOLOCK)  

   SELECT  
     TenderID,  
     TenderRefNumber,  
     TenderTitle,  
     subProductCatName,  
     CreatedDate,  
     UserName,  
     ModifiedDate,  
     ModifiedUserName,  
     tRecordCount  
   FROM (  
   SELECT  
     TD.TenderID,  
     TD.TenderRefNumber,  
     TD.TenderTitle,  
     TD.SubProductCatName,  
     TD.CreatedDate,  
     TD.UserName,  
     TD.ModifiedDate,  
     TD.ModifiedUserName,  
     ROW_NUMBER()OVER (  
     ORDER BY TD.TenderID desc  
     )AS RowNum,  
     @recordCount AS tRecordCount,  
     TD.Enabled,  
     COUNT(TC.TenderID)AS NoOFCorrigendum  
    FROM  
     [vwTenderDetail] TD(NOLOCK)  
    LEFT JOIN  
     TenderCorrigendum TC(NOLOCK)  
    ON  
     TD.TenderID = TC.TenderID  
    WHERE  
     TD.Enabled= 1  
    GROUP BY  
     TD.TenderID,  
     TD.TenderRefNumber,  
     TD.TenderTitle,  
     TD.SubProductCatName,  
     TD.CreatedDate,  
     TD.UserName,  
     TD.ModifiedDate,  
     TD.ModifiedUserName,  
     TD.Enabled  
    )AS TEMP  

  WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @startRowIndex  
  AND @endRowIndex  
  END
```

Answer (score 1):

just put the `order by` on the outside query. not sure if that is what you want but it will make the error go away:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetAllTender]
      @pageIndex int = 0
    , @pageSize int = 0
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
/* Set Starting Row Index and Ending Row Index */
-------------------------------------------------  
DECLARE @startRowIndex int = 0
SET @startRowIndex = (@pageIndex * @pageSize) + 1
DECLARE @endRowIndex int = 0
SET @endRowIndex = (@startRowIndex + @pageSize - 1)
/* recordCount required for paging in front end */
DECLARE @recordCount int = 0
SET @recordCount = 0
-------------------------------------------------  
SELECT
    @recordCount = COUNT(*)
FROM [vwTenderDetail] A WITH (NOLOCK)
SELECT
    TenderID,
    TenderRefNumber,
    TenderTitle,
    subProductCatName,
    CreatedDate,
    UserName,
    ModifiedDate,
    ModifiedUserName,
    tRecordCount
FROM (SELECT
    TD.TenderID,
    TD.TenderRefNumber,
    TD.TenderTitle,
    TD.SubProductCatName,
    TD.CreatedDate,
    TD.UserName,
    TD.ModifiedDate,
    TD.ModifiedUserName,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    ORDER BY TD.TenderID
    ) AS RowNum,
    @recordCount AS tRecordCount,
    TD.Enabled,
    COUNT(TC.TenderID) AS NoOFCorrigendum
FROM [vwTenderDetail] TD (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN TenderCorrigendum TC (NOLOCK)
    ON TD.TenderID = TC.TenderID
WHERE TD.Enabled = 1
GROUP BY TD.TenderID,
         TD.TenderRefNumber,
         TD.TenderTitle,
         TD.SubProductCatName,
         TD.CreatedDate,
         TD.UserName,
         TD.ModifiedDate,
         TD.ModifiedUserName,
         TD.Enabled
) AS TEMP
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @startRowIndex
AND @endRowIndex
ORDER BY TenderID DESC         
END
```